# Show that there are $n^{n^2}$ different binary operations on a set $A$ of order $n$.

Tags: combinatorics, binary-operations

In Sets and Groups by Green excesses 1 for Chapter 4 reads:

"1 Show that there are $n^{n^2}$ different binary operations on a set $A$ of order $n$. Find all sixteen binary operations on $A=\{a,b\}$. How many are (i) commutative, (ii) associative, (iii) have unit elements, or (iv) have zero elements?"

Can somebody give a **hint** on solving this question; starting from why is there $n^{n^2}$ different binary operations on a set $A$ of order $n$?

If you represent binary operation on $A$ by the multiplication table, then you'll get a map of $A\times A$ into $A$ which is only $n^n$.

Comment: Hint: how many mappings are there $X \to Y$? How many elements does $A \times A$ have? How many elements does $A$ have?

Comment: But $(n^n)^2$ is merely $n^{2n}$. Don't you mean $n^{n^2}$?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen very sorry about this. I've corrected the mistake.

Comment: Given that $A=\{a,b\}$ @MeesdeVries  how many mappings are there X→Y? >> I want to say 4: $a\rightarrow a$, $a\rightarrow b$, $b\rightarrow a$ and $b\rightarrow b$ How many elements does A×A have? >> I imagine A×A as being a table with following mappings a*a, a*b, b*a, b*b. How many elements does A have? >> so cordiality of A is 2 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right lines: you say

> If you represent binary operation on $A$ by the multiplication table, then you'll get a map of $A\times A$ into $A$ which is only $n^n$.

but in fact a map from $A$ (i.e. a set of size $n$) into $A$ would have $n^n$ possibilities; here $A\times A$ is a set of size $n^2$.